# Get date of last seven days

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I want to get date of last seven days from now.For example current date is

`02-10-2016,` get date of seven days like this

```
01-10-2016,30-09-2016,29-09-2016,28-09-2016,27-09-2016,26-09-2016
```

My code

```
string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateTime lastWeek = dt.AddDays(-7.0);
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't convert it to a string. Simply do: `DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;`, then you can add days to it. The `string` type does not have a `AddDays` method but I'm sure the compiler already told you that. As such, when you get error messages which becomes the reason you come here to ask you should mention the exception type (if it's an exception) as well as the error message.

Comment: You already know how you can get the date of seven days ago. You surely are able to figure out how to get the date 6 days ago, 5 days ago, … `AddDays` is a method on the DateTime object though, so you need to do that before your `ToString` call.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Although i agree with you, this would depend on what the OP is trying to use dt for.

Comment: @SimonPrice No, it wouldn't. If he's manipulating dates he should use DateTime (or some other date-related library), not strings.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen i think you have missed my point, if he is outputting this to a label or a textbox control then he would want to put this to a string. Its wrong to assume that your way is the right way rather than what the poster is trying to do

Comment: Please write context (programming language for example) together with more info in the subject, so people will be able to answer it.

Comment: @SimonPrice I'm not missing the point in my opinion. If he wants to output it to labels or text or whatever then obviously he needs to use `string.Format`, `DateTime.ToString` or whatever but he must do so *after* he has calculated the correct dates, because that calculation is about the dates, not about the text and the type in .NET to do this with is `DateTime`, not strings.

Comment: we will have to agree to disagree then

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`AddDays` is a part of `DateTime`, not of `string`.
You need to build your dates iteratively and then convert it to a string.

```
DateTime[] last7Days = Enumerable.Range(0, 7)
    .Select(i => DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-i))
    .ToArray();

foreach (var day in last7Days)
    Console.WriteLine($"{day:yyyy-MM-dd}"); // Any manipulations with days go here
```

Comment: @user7063016 You could just change `yyyy-MM-dd` pattern to `yyyy/MM/dd` or whatever you want. Read more about `DateTime` and its formatting at [dotnetperls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime) and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 5):

Without LINQ, with a simple loop:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

for (int i=0;i<7;i++)
{
      dt = dt.AddDays(-1);
      Console.WriteLine(dt.Date.ToShortDateString());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using *Linq*:

```
  var date = new DateTime(2016, 10, 2);

  var result = Enumerable.Range(1, 7)
    .Select(day => date.Date.AddDays(- day))
    .ToArray(); // if you want to represent dates as an array
```

Test

```
  // 01-10-2016,30-09-2016,29-09-2016,28-09-2016,27-09-2016,26-09-2016,25-09-2016
  Console.Write(string.Join(",", result.Select(d => d.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"))));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, the AddDays method will add only a specific number of days to the given data and dives you the resulted date. But here in your case you need a list of dates, so you have to loop through those dates and get them as well. I hope the following method will help you to do this:

```
 public static string GetLast7DateString()
 {
     DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
     return String.Join(",",Enumerable.Range(0, 7)
                                      .Select(x => currentDate.AddDays(-x).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"))
                                      .ToList());
 }
```

**Note :** If you want to exclude the current date means you have to  take the range from `7` and the count should be `7`. You can read more about [`Enumerable.Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx) here

If you call this method like the following means you will get the output as `24-10-2016,23-10-2016,22-10-2016,21-10-2016,20-10-2016,19-10-2016,18-10-2016`

```
 string opLast7Days = GetLast7DateString();
```

Comment: Shouldn't be `Enumerable.Range(1,7)`? OP wants the 7 previous days.

Comment: If you start with `1` means you will lost current date, let me update notes to the answer, thank you for the comment

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static List<DateTime> getLastSevenDate(DateTime currentDate)
        {
            List<DateTime> lastSevenDate = new List<DateTime>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
            {
                lastSevenDate.Add(currentDate.AddDays(-i));
            }
            return lastSevenDate;
        }
```