# Get past 7 days as string

Tags: c#

I am looking to get the past 7 days as string in real time. I do not need to get all the days as such. I am only looking for something like this:

```
string seventh_day = "2021-02-17";
string first_day = "2021-02-11";
```

How do I get it in Unity?

Comment: What is the problem? What had you tried so far? ... iterate enumerable range and substract days from today then format

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime ...

Comment: `DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get date of last seven days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40212347/get-date-of-last-seven-days)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can e.g. simply use [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.op_subtraction#System_DateTime_op_Subtraction_System_DateTime_System_TimeSpan_)

```
var strings = new List<string>();
var now = DateTime.Now;
for(var i = 7; i > 0; i--)
{
    var day = now.AddDays(-i);
    strings.Add(day.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
}

foreach(var day in strings)
{
    Debug.Log(day);
}
```

Results in

```
2021-02-11
2021-02-12 
2021-02-13 
2021-02-14 
2021-02-15 
2021-02-16
2021-02-17
```